# Should I switch from intel core i3 2100 to i5 2500k or i7 2770k for easy working in android studio in 2019

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, memory, ssd

I currently own an old pc with 2gb ram, i3 2100 and with no gpu. So i am thinking to upgrade it to i5 2500k or i7 2700k with 16 gb ram, nvidia 710 2 gb vram and 320 gb ssd Will it be enough to carry out my programming and android studio needs ? 
Help me to choose the best in budget and **will this upgrade be any worth or not ??** And tell me whether i will need dedicated gpu or not

Comment: I7 2700k is nearly 8 years old, have you thought of getting a new motherboard?

Comment: @SeanJ It still holds its own pretty good if you don't need newer features like M.2, the latest graphics card, or do really high end stuff.It would be a decent upgrade on a small budget.

Answer (score 2):

This upgrade will definitely be worth it. The gpu isn't the most demanding part though. The 16gb ram and the i7 will definitely be worth it. A lot of cores/threads is probably the most important as the studio is quite taxing on resources.